# Where is the documentations for Java EWS API 1.2 Library?

Tags: java, .net, documentation, exchangewebservices

Im looking for a documentation for the Java EWS API 1.2 Library from microsoft and also for that from independentsoft.webdav for .NET. Is there no documentation or do I just not find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documentation specifically for EWS Java aside from the Word file that comes with it. However, the documentation for the [C# EWS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is available, and the examples are largely applicable to the Java API. Usually you only need to take into account the differences between the languages, which are not that great, at least not as far as the examples are concerned.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Do you know it also for the .Net library from independentsoft.webdav?

Comment: I haven't used the Independentsoft libraries, so I couldn't say for sure how their documentation works out.

Comment: The EWS Java API is now available on github as an open source project.  The document was ported to markdown and you are welcome to contribute more examples.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/

Comment: This might help, Even though these are for C# but you will be able to find similar classes in Java library. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange

Answer (score 0):

user1017413 is maybe right that you can use the documentation of the C# EWS API, but if you still looking for the documentation for that api:
The API is available in Maven repository, so you can still use the [Maven generated javadoc](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Acom.microsoft.ews-java-api).